# Is it ok to write unit tests for private method for this Expression evaluator class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, expression

I have tho following code

```
public interface IInterpreter
{
    decimal Evaluate(string expression);
}

public class Interpreter : IInterpreter
{
    public decimal Evaluate(string expression)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(expression))
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameter " + nameof(expression) + " cannot be empty");

        var rpnExpression = ConvertToReversePolishNotation(expression);
        return EvaluateReversePolishExpression(rpnExpression);
    }
...
 }
```

This class will evaluate expressions like "5+5*6" or "(3-5)*(2+2) +5" 
Now i want to write unit tests. The only public function here is `Evaluate` and according to all recomendation only this method should be tested.  
The problem is that i have a strong feeling that both `ConvertToReversePolishNotation(expression)`  `EvaluateReversePolishExpression(rpnExpression)` functions have to be covered with unit tests ... If some unit test will fail for `Evaluate` method it will not point me out where is the bug (in `ConvertToRPNExpression` method or in `EvaluateReversePolishExpression` function).


So the question is - **Is it ok in this case to write unit tests for private functions ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Refactor the `ConvertToReversePolishNotation` method to a seperate class. Its concern is conversion.

The concern of the Interpreter is to evaluate. If you 'mock' the output of the conversion it should be easy to test using the public `Evaluate` method.

Comment: @Disappointed you can use the 'Single Responsibility Principle' to validate whether the class is to complex. Usually your unit testing problem is a good indicator,

Answer (score 3):

I would create three classes, one responsible for the validation, one for the Conversion and one for the Evaluation.

Than use constructor dependency injection to decouple from the actual implementation.
Either you instantiate it manually or you delegate the Container to initiate it, you will be able to change the behavior without the need of mutating the Interpreter.

If you go down this route, you can easily test the order of invocation of the dependency, so you will test the behavior of the Interpreter.
Like, Validation, Conversion, Evaluation.

Separately than you can test each implementation of the single classes.

Your class is also braking the single responsibility principle, because is responsible to validate and also to call external classes do perform an operation, so is responsible to describe a flow of events.

Also, if you tightly couple the implementation classes for Conversion and Evaluation, you are breaking the Open Close principle.

Comment: The validation is just a simple guard. Why move input guard to a seperate class?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is okay.**.

You are unit testing `Evaluate` which goes through the actual implementation of the `ConvertToReversePolishNotation` and `EvaluateReversePolishExpression`.

Aphelion is right that you can separate the class for its own responsibility, but only for `ConvertToReversePolishNotation` you wouldn't even need to create a private method for  `EvaluateReversePolishExpression` if you do that, because that's already what it's doing (for now). Before calling evaluate, the caller should call the class for `ConvertToReversePolishNotation` and pass it in as a parameter.

If you are also concerned about not unit testing `private` methods, then you can use `internal` methods.

Out of topic: You also have to keep in mind on how to extend and scale this feature. What would happen if your interpreter also wants to return a data type besides `decimal`? Wouldn't you want to maximize generics too?

```
public decimal Evaluate(string expression)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(expression))
        throw new ArgumentException("Parameter " + nameof(expression) + " cannot be empty");

    return EvaluateReversePolishExpression(expression);
}
```

Comment: as i understand you agree with @Aphelion but your short answer is Yes while his is Not :)

Comment: @Disappointed I agree that you can separate it, I don't agree with his `No` that it's not okay to not write unit tests for private functions. Which basically was your bolded question. Sometimes it's really just inevitable to ignore. Just because one of the books/authors said it's bad to write unit tests for private function doesn't mean it's a hard rule.

Comment: Well, his question was `in this case` and not a hard rule ofcouse :)